# He's 16 and she's 14.

Tags: relative-pronouns, ellipsis, contractions

Do the sentences below sound natural?

> I have a brother and a sister. He's 16 and she's 14.

Or should you say, 'My brother is 16 and my sister is 14.'?

Comment: Both of those sentences sound fine.

Comment: As Angela's comment (née answer) says, it's fine.  *He* and *she* unambiguously refer back to *brother* and *sister* respectively.

Comment: As things stand, it's "unclear what you're asking". Can you explain *why* you think the first version might not be "natural"? For example, are you bothered that the (semantic) links between *he/she* and *brother/sister* might not be strong enough to justify the "backward reference"?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Sorry, I know I was not clear enough. I didn't know how to write it. I was told that it's strange to say "He's 16 and she's 14" in parallel. He said I should say "I have a brother and a sister. The brother is 16 and the sister is 14." But it didn't sound right to me, but I couldn't explain it clearly.

Comment: Okay, another way - I have a brother and a sister aged 16 and 14 **respectively.**

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways of saying siblings' ages.

- I have a brother and a sister. He's 16 and she's 14.
- I have a brother and a sister. He is 16 years old and she is 14.
- I have a brother who's 16 years old, and a sister who's 14.
- I have a brother, 16 years old, and a sister who's 14.
- I have a 16-year-old brother and a sister who's 14.
- I have a brother and a sister. My brother is 16 and my sister is 14.

All of the above are grammatically correct. The second example is a longer version than the first, but the OP's original sentence sounds more natural because it contains contractions. Just be careful though to ***never*** make these typical Italian learners mistakes:

*I have a brother and a sister. He has 16 years and she has 14 year* * = **NO!**